# RBX Automatic messaging bot not working

Tags: php, lua

Trying to insert a automatic-messaging system in roblox, but its not working.
(Script was to complicated to post here apparently)
http://pastebin.com/tbFRY1Az

Whenever I go to

mywebsite.com/newMessage.php?id=2262712 and it doesnt work

anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but Roblox has a message limitation system. This prevents message bots from spamming inboxes. Scroll to the bottom of [this Pastebin post](http://pastebin.com/n5uKZiJV) and you will see a javascript PM bot. It works to the extent of the anti-spam PM system that Roblox has.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that php-curl is not installed/enabled

add following lines to the start of the file (after

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will probably show any errors occuring(depending on the server config).

If it doesn't display any errors, create a file with this code:

```
<?php
  phpinfo(8);
?>
```

Then open it in browser, it will display all modules enabled, search for "curl", if it's there, then you have to check your error logs to see what's wrong with the code, if not, then you have to install php-curl to get it to work(or rewrite the code so it uses another method of fetching data).

**UPD** For some reason you don't have curl_init, add this on line 8(above all curl_setopt's):

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.roblox.com/newlogin");
```

Also, replace

```
htmlspecialchars($_GET($key));
```

with

```
htmlspecialchars($_GET[$key]);
```